# JSP - Read page's meta tag

Tags: mysql, jsp

What I need to do is read in the meta tag of an html file (it's the keyword meta tag) and I was wondering if it was possible with JSP? I need it because I am accessing a database, but the MySQL search is based off of the keyword. Is this possible? If so, do you know how?

SO essentially my MySQL is:

```
"SELECT * FROM db WHERE searchterm= [KEYWORD META TAG]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your own custom tag, which outputs the meta tag, then you can easily store the value somewhere when the tag is run.

**EDIT**

That assumed that your meta tags are on a JSP page.  If they're not (as you indicated in comments), and you need to extract them from an external HTML file, then you're going need an HTML parser of some sort (or some ugly/unreliable regular expressions).   You might want to try something like http://jsoup.org/.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that statement... Do you mean create my own custom meta tag?

Comment: Yes exactly.  So you make yourNamespace:meta, and then use that in your JSP just as you would use a normal meta tag.  But in your tag's definition, in addition to just producing a meta tag as output, you can also capture the value in it.

Comment: Would you be able to post an example? I am extremely new to JSP.

Comment: There are two ways to make custom tags.  There's the "old" way (with Java classes): http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm, and the "new" way (with HTML-like tag files):http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jserverpages3_ch11/.  Personally I recommend the tag file way (and I just generally recommend learning about tag files; they're an extremely useful tool for a JSP developer).

Comment: That's not really going to work. I need to be able to read the META tags of an HTML file. The meta tags are from an external file not the JSP file.